How to enable Tailwind CSS Intellisense when pair programming using live share?
So, me and my partners were building a website using Tailwind CSS and React JS. The main project is located locally in my PC.
I use VSCode and Live Share extension for us to work together at the same time. But the problem is on my partners interface, the intellisense (something like code suggestion/completion) is not showing.
We already installed the Tailwind CSS Intellisense and all setup were done, but it's still not showing up.
Is there any way to solve that or no? Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
